# Prediction limit or intervals in neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a simple graph neural network in TensorFlow/python which I use in regression.

My dataset y-values are always in the interval of [0,1] as a float number.

But a lot of predictions are smaller than 0 or larger than 1. This issue greatly reduces performance.

Is there any way I can set a limit (or interval) in tf that will restrict the algorithm to predict something outside the range?

I was thinking of applying some penalties during training.

**Note**: I think this is different from regularization because I do not have overfitting issues.

**Note**: I have a fairly small dataset with around 400 data points.

Comment: Use `sigmoid` function for output layer, in order to limit the output between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure of the architecture of your neural network. However, a sigmoid activation function should restrict the output values between [0, 1].

You can find more information here - https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/activations/sigmoid